# Spark Inactivity - Spark Driver stop reading data using TCP streaming after few minutes

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-streaming

I am facing strange issue and tried using Custom Receiver as well.

Issue - Spark Driver/Executor stop receiving and displaying data in stdout after 5 min of Activity. It continuously work if we keep writing data to server socket at the other end.
**There is no error reported in driver or executors logs.**
Code snippet

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://10.0.0.5:7077").setAppName("SmartAudioAnalytics")
            .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g").set("spark.cores.max", "5").set("spark.driver.cores", "2")
            .set("spark.driver.memory", "2g");
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(3000));

    JavaDStream<String> JsonReq1 = ssc.socketTextStream("myip", 9997, StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
    JavaDStream<String> JsonReq2 = ssc.socketTextStream("myIP", 9997, StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
    ArrayList<JavaDStream<String>> streamList = new ArrayList<JavaDStream<String>>();
    streamList.add(JsonReq1);
    JavaDStream<String> UnionStream = ssc.union(JsonReq2, streamList);

    UnionStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        int total = 0;

        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) throws Exception {

            long count = rdd.count();
            total += count;
            System.out.println(total);
            rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {

                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void call(String s) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }

            });
        }
    });
    System.out.println(UnionStream.count());
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

I have opened Spark UI and find all threads are working properly even after 24 hours. Please see pictures [image][image]